# adding values in a hashmap from lisked lists

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

i have 2 array list like `list 1 : [BRONZE1|BRONZE2|BRONZE3]` and `list2 :[ABC,XYZ|ACO|PMP,PCSH]`

I want to put these values in a Hashmap like : `<BRONZE1,ABC,XYZ>,<BRONZE2,ACO>,<BRONZE3,PMP,PCSH>.`

Can someone suggest.

Comment: Your hashmap looks like a list. What are the keys and values?

Comment: Iterate on both lists with same counter, get the value from lists, use first as key of the map, and second as value of the map

Comment: key will be first value from list1 and value will be first value from list 2 till the | delimiter

Comment: Nadir--i tried doing it. Can u post a code snippet for this?

Comment: If both the lists are of same length, you can try what @Nadir suggested.

Comment: You should better post what you tried and people can help you with what didn't work.

Comment: The catch here is that both lists could be of different sizes too.

Comment: for(int i=0; i<list1.size();i++){
 Object key = list1.get(i);
 Object value = list2.get(i);
 map.put(key,value)
}

Comment: If the size is different, use smaller to limit size. Then do what your requirements are with the rest

Comment: The size for both will be 1, since its | delimited.

Comment: So first create a proper lists from your input, split the strings on | or whatever your input is.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote it seems you have List at the value of your map.
You can use `Map<String, List<String>>` and use `StringUtils.split` or `String.split` to get the data.
Something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
List<String> keys = keysStr.split("|");
List<String> vals = valuesStr.split("|");
for(int i=0;i<keys.size();++i){
    myMap.put(key, vals.get(i).split(","));
}
```

Add some checks and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 List list1 = new ArrayList();
        list1.add("abc");
        list1.add("def");
        list1.add("nop");
        List list2 = new ArrayList();
        list2.add("ghi");
        list2.add("jkl");
        Map map = new HashMap();
        Iterator it1 = list1.iterator();
        Iterator it2 = list2.iterator();
        while(it1.hasNext()){
            if(it2.hasNext()){
                map.put(it1.next(), it2.next());
            }else{
                map.put(it1.next(), "");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows a class derived form HashMap, Its constructor may answer your query

```
public class HashMapAuto <K, V> extends HashMap
{    
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
     public HashMapAuto(List<K> keys, List<V> values) throws Exception
     {        
        super();        
        if (keys.size() != values.size()) 
             throw new Exception("'keys' list and 'values' list differs in size");
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
        {            
             Object newKey = keys.get(i);
             Object newValue = values.get(i);
             this.put(newKey, newValue);        
        }    
     }
 }
```